# How to use DISTINCT with string_agg() and to_timestamp()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, aggregate, distinct

I want comma separated unique `from_date` in one row.

So I am using `distinct()` function in `TO_TIMESTAMP()` but getting errors.

```
SELECT string_agg(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(distinct(from_date) / 1000), 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ',')
FROM trn_day_bookkeeping_income_expense 
GROUP BY from_date,enterprise_id having enterprise_id = 5134650;
```

I want output like:

```
01-10-2017,01-11-2017,01-12-2017
```

But I am getting errors like:

> ```
> ERROR:  DISTINCT specified, but to_timestamp is not an aggregate function
> LINE 1: SELECT string_agg(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(distinct(from_date) /...**
> ```

Comment: what data type is `from_date` Why do you use `to_timestamp()` on it? Why aren't you storing timestamp values in a `timestamp` column?

Comment: data type is bigint. to_timestamp()  is using for convert bigint to date with format

Comment: Why aren't you storing timestamp values in a `timestamp` column? then you wouldn't need to call `to_timestamp()` everytime you want a proper timestamp

Comment: please suggest me how to store timestamp values in a timestamp

Comment: Use the data type `timestamp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`DISTINCT`** is neither a function nor an operator but an SQL construct or syntax element. Can be added as leading keyword [to the whole `SELECT` list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) or [within most aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Add it to the `SELECT` list (consisting of a single column in your case) in a subselect where you can also cheaply add `ORDER BY`. Should yield  best performance:

```
SELECT string_agg(to_char(the_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ',') AS the_dates
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT to_timestamp(from_date / 1000)::date AS the_date
   FROM   trn_day_bookkeeping_income_expense 
   WHERE  enterprise_id = 5134650
   ORDER  BY the_date   -- assuming this is the order you want 
   ) sub;
```

First generate dates (multiple distinct values may result in the same date!).
Then the `DISTINCT` step (or `GROUP BY`).
(While being at it, optionally add `ORDER BY`.)
Finally aggregate.

An index on `(enterprise_id)` or better `(enterprise_id, from_date)` should greatly improve performance.

Ideally, timestamps are stored as type `timestamp` to begin with. Or `timestamptz`. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

**`DISTINCT ON`** is a Postgres-specific extension of standard SQL `DISTINCT` functionality. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

***Alternatively***, you could also add `DISTINCT`(*and* `ORDER BY`) to the aggregate function `string_agg()` directly:

```
SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT to_char(to_timestamp(from_date / 1000), 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ',' ORDER BY to_char(to_timestamp(from_date / 1000), 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AS the_dates
FROM   trn_day_bookkeeping_income_expense 
WHERE  enterprise_id = 5134650
```

But that would be ugly, hard to read and maintain, and more expensive. (Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`).

Comment: @Rahul: I added some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`distinct` is not a function, it's an operator applied to either all columns in the select list, or a parameter to an aggregate function.

you probably want this:

```
SELECT string_agg(distinct TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(from_date / 1000), 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ',') 
from trn_day_bookkeeping_income_expense 
group by from_date,enterprise_id 
having enterprise_id = 5134650
```